# Transparent background for mdframed environment?

Tags: backgrounds, transparency, mdframed

Is it possible to specify a transparent background colour for the mdframed environment, so that anything which might be underneath will be visible?

Comment: `mdframed` can use `TikZ` and with the `tikzsetting` option you can pass arguments to `tikzset`. This way you should be able to change the opacity. I can't test this right now, but you can give it a try.

Comment: I only want the background to be transparent, not the borders or text. Is this possible using 'tikzset' ?

Comment: Like I said, I can't test this right now. But there is a `fill opacity` in TikZ that should only affect the background.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must set the opacity to the whole environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\SetBgContents{top secret}
\SetBgColor{red}
%  \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={fill=red,opacity=0.1,draw=green}}%
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,},settings={\tikzset{every picture/.style={opacity=0.6}}}]{myenvironment}
\begin{document}
\BgThispage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,fill] (0,0) rectangle (8,4);
\node[text width=8cm] {\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{myenvironment}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makers the text and the frame also transparent. But the solution suggested by Philippe Goutet in a comment to another answer seems to work.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the comments, you can set `mdframed` to use `TikZ`. Here is a MWE that sets the `fill opacity` to `0.5`; you can tweak it to whatever you would like between `0` (fully transparent, or invisible) and `1` (fully opaque, or solid)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5}]{myenvironment}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

---

Following @PhilippeGoutet's comment, you can use

```
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5},backgroundcolor=none]{myenvironment}
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't give me what I want. If this box overlays any other text, I want to be able to see it.
eg.

`\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
 
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5}]{myenvironment} 
 
\begin{document} 
\vtop to 0pt{\LARGE Some text underneath}
\begin{myenvironment} 
\lipsum[1] 
\end{myenvironment} 
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Dan I see the problem now- note that this wasn't completely obvious in your original question; this would have been a good place for a MWE. I'll work on your updated problem :)

Comment: Yes, my apologies, you are right, I should have provided an example, but I had no idea how to achieve the effect. I very much appreciate your efforts to help.

Comment: @Dan: use `\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=red,fill opacity=0.5},backgroundcolor=none]{myenvironment}`

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Thank you very much, see my edit :)

Comment: @Dan: see the update

Comment: @cmhughes The border never completely disappears although, I tried the following: `\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=white, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=0}]{myenvironment}`