# Boxed notes in MusixTeX

Tags: framed, music, musixtex

I need to put a box around some notes in a MusixTeX score. I've tried with `\fcolorbox`, but I get a white background (not transparent), covering the staff lines. I've also tried with Tikz, but I don't get the right spacing and positioning of notes. Any idea?

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex,musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\startextract
\NOtes\wh{cde}\wh{f}\wh{g}\en
\endextract
% I want to box the F note with a red box
\startextract
\NOtes\wh{cde}\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\wh{f}}\wh{g}\en
\endextract
\startextract
\NOtes\wh{cde}\tikz[overlay]\node[draw,red]{\wh{f}};\wh{g}\en
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the solution of using just an fbox presented in the answer here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59383/how-to-keep-transparent-fcolor-box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library and a `\FrameNote` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex,musixtex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\NewDocumentCommand\FrameNote{mO{0pt}O{14pt}O{10pt}}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner ysep=0pt,draw,red,text width=#4,minimum height=#3,anchor=west] at ([xshift=-4.5pt,yshift=\the\dimexpr#2-5pt\relax]pic cs:#1) {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\startextract
\NOtes\wh{c}\wh{d}\wh{efg}\ha{p}\en
\endextract
\startextract
\NOtes\tikzmark{a}\wh{c}\tikzmark{b}\wh{d}\tikzmark{c}\wh{efg}\tikzmark{d}\ha{p}\en
\endextract
\end{music}

\FrameNote{a}
\FrameNote{b}[4pt]
\FrameNote{c}[8pt][14pt][60pt]
\FrameNote{d}[26pt][24pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\tikzmark{<mark>}` to place a mark at the desired location (typically just before a note or a group of notes that you want to frame). Then use the `\FrameCommand{<mark>}` to draw the frame. The command has three optional arguments allowing to control the vertical shift of the frame, its width and its height; the complete syntax is:

```
\FrameCommand{<mark>}[<vertical shift>][<height>][<width>]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed. I didn't know de `tikzmark` library nor te `xparse` package, this is a great discovery.

Comment: @Francisco You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. I know you've up-voted, but accepting is a different action. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).