# Background colors with mdframed: is this behavior normal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, boxes, mdframed, transparency

### Introduction

With the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38298/8323), I tried to define a semi-transparent background for a theorem-like environment. Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myStyle}{%
tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5},
backgroundcolor=none
}

\mdtheorem[style=myStyle]{test}{Test}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue}
\begin{test}
This is a test
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The strange behavior

But looking for this solution, I encountered a strange behavior of `mdframed`. I wanted to post about it for the community and maybe have more information. Here is what happens if I don't give the option `backgroundcolor=none`. Please compare the two codes and the two images to see what is the strange behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myStyle}{%
tikzsetting={draw=blue,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5}
}

\mdtheorem[style=myStyle]{test}{Test}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue}
\begin{test}
This is a test
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

### Question

So, my question could be: is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing order:

1. The background of the whole frame including the frametitle is filled by   `backgroundcolor`.  The default `backgroundcolor` is white. `backgroundcolor=none` means `fill=none`
2. Then the `tikzsetting` is executed for the whole frame.
3. At the end the frametitlebackground is filled by the `frametitlebackgroundcolor`. If no `frametitlebackgroundcolor` is set, the `backgroundcolor` is also used for the `frametitlebackgroundcolor`.

Thus to get a semi-transparent background you can use

```
\mdfdefinestyle{myStyle}{%
  backgroundcolor=none,% both the background of the whole frame and the background of the frame title are not filled
  tikzsetting={fill=red,fill opacity=0.5},% 
}
```

[image]

Or you can use

```
\mdfdefinestyle{myStyle}{%
  apptotikzsetting={%
  \tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={fill=red,fill opacity=0.5}}% the background of the whole frame is filled red with opacity=0.5
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=none% the background of the frametitle is not filled 
}
```